# Why does the request method is always called with end equals null?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am currently creating an app to store and read encrypted files, and I am implementing a way to play an audio file, to do this I installed the packages `just_audio` and `audio_service`. But to make the loading times faster for the app to not be at 2 fps when the user loads a big audio file into memory and to always wait for the next chunk of data to be decrypted, I wanted to create a buffer system into my `StreamAudioSource`, so I wrote this code: (NOTE: I can't give a working demo without giving whole app (I don't know if I can give it on stackoverflow but it is on my github))

```dart
class EncryptedAudioSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final Stream<List<int>> streamedData;
  List<int> bufferedData = [];
  Completer? targetCompleter;
  int? currentTarget;
  final String mimeType;
  final int fileByteLength;

  EncryptedAudioSource(this.streamedData, this.mimeType, this.fileByteLength, {super.tag = 'EncryptedAudioSource'}) {
    streamedData.listen((receivedData) {
      bufferedData += receivedData;
      if(currentTarget != null && bufferedData.length >= currentTarget!) {
        if(targetCompleter != null) {
          targetCompleter!.complete();
        }
        currentTarget = null;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    debugPrint('asked for $start to $end length is $fileByteLength');
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bufferedData.length;

    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: fileByteLength,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bufferedData.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: mimeType,
    );
  }
}

class AudioPlayerHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with SeekHandler {
  final _player = AudioPlayer();

  AudioPlayerHandler() {
    _player.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
  }

  void playFile(MediaItem item, EncryptedAudioSource source) {
    mediaItem.add(item);
    _player.setAudioSource(source);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() async {
    if(playbackState.value.processingState == AudioProcessingState.ready) {
      _player.play();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> pause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> stop() => _player.stop();

  PlaybackState _transformEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
    return PlaybackState(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.rewind,
        if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.fastForward,
      ],
      systemActions: const {
        MediaAction.seek,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      },
      androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: const {
        ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
        ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
        ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
        ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
        ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
      }[_player.processingState]!,
      playing: _player.playing,
      updatePosition: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
      queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
    );
  }
}
```

But when I actually run the app and this code, this is in general what is printed:

```
asked for null to null length is 10195448
asked for 65765 to null length is 10195448
asked for 219 to null length is 10195448
asked for 101071 to null length is 10195448
asked for 101071 to null length is 10195448
asked for 101071 to null length is 10195448
asked for 101071 to null length is 10195448
```

And the app eventually reads the file in debug mode (after all its content was given, also for this example the file was 10 minutes long). But then if I read a 50mb+ file (Science Friday like on the `just_audio` pub.dev) the app runs at 2 fps (in release and debug mode) and does not run the file. Also the app does not work in release mode but I will likely figure this later.

My app is on android/iOS (but the iOS part is not my priority for the moment)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 2 fps? If you're talking about Frames Per Second, I suggest you use DevTools to track down where exactly all the CPU is being used. Considering that Dart is single-threaded, you need to manually put heavy processing into a separate isolate from the main/UI isolate. I can't determine it myself, but it might be the decryption code. If it turns out to be within just_audio, you can report a bug to get it fixed.

Comment: All my decryption code is asynchronous by design, it uses an implementation for the platform of the device the method is called on, I think this issue comes from the bus between the main isolate and the platform implementation, I think that decoding and encoding the data that much will not let any render data to be given to the operating system.